# Connect phpMyAdmin in app engine to MySQL in compute engine with private IP

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, phpmyadmin, google-compute-engine

I have installed and setup phpMyAdmin in app engine, with MySQL installed in compute engine. I am receiving this error mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory when logging into phpMyAdmin. I have set up vpc access connector in app.yaml, and opened port 3306 in the compute engine.

[image]

config.inc.php in phpMyAdmin:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '10.126.0.9:3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

in compute engine with MySQL installed
with config **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf**

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
# pid-file      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# port          = 3306
# datadir       = /var/lib/mysql


# If MySQL is running as a replication slave, this should be
# changed. Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir
# tmpdir                = /tmp
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 10.126.0.9
#mysqlx-bind-address     = 0.0.0.0
```

On top of that, I have created user to login from phpMyAdmin

```
CREATE USER 'myadminLogin'@'*' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

MySQL and OS variant

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 10.126.0.9:3306         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32879/mysqld        
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                        :::*                    LISTEN      32879/mysqld
```

Port opened: 3306:

[image]

Network analysis:

[image]

### Update

After the above changes, I no longer see the login panel but currently being directed straight to the page below. What is the issue?

[image]

Comment: The default installation of MySQL listens on a Unix socket. Did you update the MYSQL configuration to listen on a network interface?

Comment: @JohnHanley May I know how can this be done?

Comment: Edit your question with more details. Which variant and version of MySQL did you install? Which operating system? In general, you configure the `bind-address and `port` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf` but the file name and location depend on system details and MySQL version. Start with guides like this one: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I have updated my ques. Is it detailed enough? Anything i have missed?

Comment: Yes, several details in my comment. Did you restart MySQL after changing mysqld.conf? Verify that MySQL is listening with the correct configuration. Post the output for lines with mysql: `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN | grep mysql`

Comment: @davidlee which is the configuration of your VM running MySQL? OS, MySQL version, etc.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I have added info as requested in the question. Thanks

Comment: Hi @RogelioMonter, OS and mysql version added at the bottom of the question. Thanks

Comment: The `mysqld.conf` configuration does not match the output from `netstat`. Note: you do not need to hide private IP addresses. Private IP addresses are `local` not `secret`. Leave them in your question as that detail might be important.

Comment: Hi '@JohnHanley, are you referring to 0.0.0.0? I thought that is allow any ingress IP for mysql. Thanks for the info. I have updated the IP address in both phpmyadmin config and netstat

Comment: With your last update, you now have a new problem. I recommend posting a new question.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I have created a new ques on the update https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73748957/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine-is-not-showing-login-screen-how-to-get-the-login-scree Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that stands out is that there's a slight mistake in your `config.inc.php`; the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '10.126.0.9:3306';` should not include the port. There's a separate directive `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']` if you need to override the default, which is 3306 so you won't even need that. Change your host line to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '10.126.0.9';` and see if that changes anything.